# Django: Page Not Found after user session expired

Tags: django

I have a django admin site which is working well, mostly.
Let's say there is an app named Example:

we have views for it:

```
@login_required
def example_index():
    something...
    return
```

url is:

```
urlpattern = patterns("", url(r'^(\d+)/index/$', example_index))
```

In the major url file, we includes above urlpattern as following:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('', url(r'^example/', include(example.urlpattern)))
```

Apparently, they are a bunch other stuff in my files, but I think I have provided all related code for this question.

After user login, user can access url /hostname/example/1001/index/. It works just fine.

Then the problem is, at some point, that when user's session has been expired, browser will return 404 Page not found if user try to refresh the page (same url: example/1001/index/).

My point is that I expect django to redirect the user to login page and redirect user back to whatever page user was after user acquire the session again. This behavior works for rest of django admin site, but not this one 'Example'.

The easy way to avoid this crash is to remove the decorator:

```
@login_required
```

But I don't want to go that way.

Does anyone know what should I do to make relogin and redirect work as expectation?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the login_url at the decorator, to redirect if the user is not logged in.

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
```

Replace login with your login url.

Comment: In fact, I have figured it out by myself. However, I got a new problem. Now the page won't crash anymore, but it won't redirect back to previous page, neither. I think it may have something to do with login_redirect_url in settings. I try to override it, no luck. The page will stay on 'hostname/login/?next=/example/1001/index/'. I mean since there is a 'NEXT' variable in url, why django ignore it?

Comment: By the way, if you can figure it out, mark is yours:)

Comment: I assume you mean the slash at the end of login_url? In fact, I thought it is weird for having that slash, but after I remove it, it still in the browser url. I mean it should 'hostname/login?next=/example/1001/index/', but ther is a '/' after login, still.

Comment: @JerryMeng: What do you want the login_url to be?

Comment: Honestly, I don't care what login_url is. I just want django redirect my browser back to whatever it was. For now, for real, my login_url is '/admin/'. it will link me to admin login page and ask user to ask. It is perfect. However, ever though I can see there is a next argument in url, django will jump to home page, '/admin/', after user login. what I wish is django take that 'next' argument seriously and jump to whatever it link to. I am thinking is there anything else I should do to trigger the redirecting? thanks for your patience!

Comment: wait a minute... Do I need to finish the redirecting by myself?! I mean I have done this before, but this is django admin site, should it be smarter? Fine, I think I should write some script to do that.